# Do I need to buy and set up domain for apps while doing server side integration for CRM+SharePoint

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, dynamics-crm, sharepoint-integration

I am presently working on Integration of Dynamics365 CRM (On Premise) and Sharepoint 2016 on premise. While pursuing Prerequisites, I have to configure apps environment for sharepoint.

So my question goes like this - Do I need to setup domain for apps along with Subscription settings service & App management service? What I think that settings up domains is extra investment which is not essentially required for SP+CRM Integration.

Any thought/Help will be appreciated. Please share valid source of information along with your answer.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like app manager service proxy required for the CRM integration. Basically for the step
"Register Microsoft Dynamics 365 with the SharePoint site collection" , we need it.

> Important

To complete these commands, the SharePoint App Management Service Application Proxy must exist and be running.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn949332.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already configured both App management service proxy & subscription setting services. Also, I have my site collection ready (w.r.t. "Register Microsoft Dynamics 365 with the SharePoint site collection"). But my question is Do I need to buy domain for apps separately?